# Mapbox event when brand new tile is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL JS API to manipulate a Mapbox map.
My question if there's an event that's capable of telling me for each HTTP request for new tile?
I finish with a code like this:

```
  map.on("dataloading", e => {
   if(e.dataType === "source" && e.source.url && e.tile) {
     //Fresh HTTP request to Mapbox API ?
   }
  });
```

Im using [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#mapdataevent) & [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map.event:dataloading) docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the primary purpose, but you should be able to use `map.transformRequest` to achieve this goal. It gets called for every request, so you'll just have to check whether it's loading a tile or something else.